# Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed at load page

Tags: php

My script load a title of url when this load by php_self in a html form.

```
<?php
$bk_url=$_REQUEST['bk_url']; 
$remote_url = $bk_url;
$from_remote_url = implode("", file("".$remote_url));
if(preg_match("/<title>(.+)<\/title>/", $from_remote_url, $regs)) {
} else {
echo "<br> Title empty. Manual insert";
}
?>
```

When load the php page, are displayed two errors:

> Warning: file(http://): failed to open stream: operation failed

and this error:

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

I have try to find a solution on stackoverflow but not find any solution.

How to fix this two errors?
Thanks

Comment: if (!strlen($_REQUEST['bk_url'])) exit("Can't run with empty URL");

Comment: Its difficult imploding on nothing `$from_remote_url = implode("", file("".$remote_url));`

Comment: Its always a good idea to check that a $_POST or $_GET parameter has actually been passed and that it actually has something in it before attempting to us it `isset()` or `empty()`

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey And if `$_REQUEST['bk_url'])` does not exist like on pages first load, **thats another error message**

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey: I try with your solution and work fine. I modify my web procedure to go at the target but work fine :) Thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Yes this trust and this is a problem. Notice: Undefined index: bk_url in

Comment: Why do you have `"".` before `$remote_url`? What's the point of concatenating an empty string?

Comment: @Barmar: I try to resolve the error file() failed to open... But not work anyway.

Comment: And you thought it was because you didn't put an empty string at the beginning of the URL? The problem is clearly that `$remote_url` doesn't contain a valid URL. What does `echo $remote_url` show?

Comment: @Barmar: when you load the page the variable is empty (this is clearly) and I to try a find solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the code only when the user has submitted the form. So check first to see if the variable is set.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['bk_url'])) {
    $bk_url=$_REQUEST['bk_url']; 
    $remote_url = $bk_url;
    $from_remote_url = implode("", file("".$remote_url));
    if(preg_match("/<title>(.+)<\/title>/", $from_remote_url, $regs)) {
    } else {
        echo "<br> Title empty. Manual insert";
    }
}
```